# Simple FOR loop in R but using different input each time

Tags: r

I would like to make a FOR loop where for each element of the variable SP (which goes from 0 to 1 with 0.05 interval each time) the loop should compute the function "epo" by taking as input each time the next number inside SP.

Once is done I want to store this results inside a matrix to keep track of every computation.

This is the code I am using

```
library(epo)
# INPUTS
x <- diff(log(EuStockMarkets))
s <- colMeans(x) 
SP = seq(from = 0, to = 1, by = 0.05) 

epo_result = epo(x = x, signal = s, lambda = 10, method = "simple", w = SP)

df           # --> matrix to be filled
```

This is what I tried but I am a beginner in terms of loops so is not working

```
for(i in 1:ncol(t(SP))){
  SP[i]= seq(from = 0, to = 1, by = 0.05)
  epo_result [i] = epo(x = x, signal = s, lambda = 10, method = "simple", w=SP[i] )
  df[i] <- c(epo_result [i])
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `lapply()` to iterate over SP.

```r
library(epo)
# INPUTS
x <- diff(log(EuStockMarkets))
s <- colMeans(x)
SP = seq(from = 0, to = 1, by = 0.05)

lapply(SP,
    \(y) epo(
      x = x,
      signal = s,
      lambda = 10,
      method = "simple",
      w = y
    ))
#> [[1]]
#> [1]  0.1914569  0.9894828 -0.3681779  0.1872382
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1]  0.1959965  0.9273004 -0.3106722  0.1873753
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1]  0.2003423  0.8709236 -0.2604761  0.1892102
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> [1]  0.2043519  0.8197200 -0.2162345  0.1921626
#> 
#> [[5]]
#> [1]  0.2079896  0.7730973 -0.1769264  0.1958395
#> 
#> [[6]]
#> [1]  0.2112650  0.7305240 -0.1417607  0.1999716
#> 
#> [[7]]
#> [1]  0.2142059  0.6915329 -0.1101109  0.2043721
#> 
#> [[8]]
#> [1]  0.21684572  0.65571644 -0.08147315  0.20891099
#> 
#> [[9]]
#> [1]  0.21921795  0.62272107 -0.05543656  0.21349754
#> 
#> [[10]]
#> [1]  0.22135393  0.59223977 -0.03166225  0.21806855
#> 
#> [[11]]
#> [1]  0.223281853  0.564005906 -0.009868083  0.222580324
#> 
#> [[12]]
#> [1] 0.22502659 0.53778739 0.01018293 0.22700308
#> 
#> [[13]]
#> [1] 0.22660990 0.51338173 0.02869136 0.23131702
#> 
#> [[14]]
#> [1] 0.2280507 0.4906117 0.0458281 0.2355095
#> 
#> [[15]]
#> [1] 0.22936542 0.46932171 0.06173975 0.23957312
#> 
#> [[16]]
#> [1] 0.23056830 0.44937484 0.07655273 0.24350413
#> 
#> [[17]]
#> [1] 0.23167171 0.43065009 0.09037668 0.24730152
#> 
#> [[18]]
#> [1] 0.2326864 0.4130403 0.1033071 0.2509662
#> 
#> [[19]]
#> [1] 0.2336218 0.3964502 0.1154277 0.2545003
#> 
#> [[20]]
#> [1] 0.2344860 0.3807949 0.1268120 0.2579070
#> 
#> [[21]]
#> [1] 0.2352863 0.3659986 0.1375249 0.2611902
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thank you so much!